# Eclipse Artifact name variable while build steps

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gcc, build

In eclipse I can use in `C/Cpp Build->Setting ->Build artifact->Artifact name`   to configure the name of the binary that export in build.

When I want to use this `Artifact name` as a variable in Post build Command, how do I do this?  $(PROJECTNAME) not give me the `Artifact name`.

Is there variable called `$(ArtifactName)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Under C/Cpp Build->Build variables define a new variable and assign it the artifact name.
Use that variable for all your needs.
I don't think that an artifact name variable exists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: artifact name  doesn't exist there . so how can I use post build command using artifact name without write it directly ?

Comment: I don't undestand how eclipse know that when I write `artifcat_name`  in `variable name` that connect to `C/Cpp Build->Setting ->Build artifact->Artifact name`

Comment: You cannot bind that. You should but a put a variable in both `C/Cpp Build->Setting ->Build artifact->Artifact name` and the post build script.